# Array Expression of form Arr[ :, num ]=1 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a little confused about this expression.Suppose y is a two dimensional array of size (30,20) and variable num=5 then the following expression shows what?

```
y[ :, num ]= 1
```

Comment: It's an assignment, so it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I know its an assignment. But 1 is assigned at which position of array y?

Comment: Are you talking about a NumPy array?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 5
y[ :, num ]= 1
```

Assuming it is a Numpy ndarray (or equivalent that uses the same notation): It assigns `1` to every item in the sixth *column*.

The colon for the first dimension specifies all items (indices) in the first dimension. The single value (`num`) for the second dimension specifies that specific index of the *series* (or sequence). In a 2-d ndarray, the first dimension is thought of as *rows* and the second dimension as *columns*.

---

[Indexing, Slicing and Iterating](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating)
[Basic Slicing and Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing)

Answer (score -1):

```
a = np.arange(600).reshape(30,20)
print(a[:5])
a[:5] =1 
print(a[:5])
```

it will just assign 1 to each index

Comment: The slice is `y[ :, num ]` not `y[ :num ]`